# ElasticSearch and inequalities

Tags: elasticsearch

Does anyone know how to perform a filter using the ElasticSearch JSON API that sets a greater than, less than, or between filter on any search results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out how to do it. You need to use a range value:

```
curl -X GET "http://0.0.0.0:9200/users/_search?pretty=true" -d '{"filter":{"range" : { "age" : { "from":20, "to": 21 } } }}'
```